# How to find the discrete Heisenberg group in this group given by a small presentation?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, heisenberg-group

Consider the group $G$ given by the following presentation:

$$G=\langle x,y\mid x^{-1}y^2xy^2=x^{-2}yx^{-2}y^3=1\rangle.$$

In this [slides](https://www.gilesgardam.com/slides/smri.pdf) it is noted that this is a torsion-free polycyclic group, which is virtually the discrete Heisenberg group, see p.16.

I am interested in the last piece of information. According to the statement, one should be able to find a copy of the Heisenberg group $H$ in $G$, such that $G/H$ is finite.

One possible presentation of the Heisenberg group is given by $$H=\langle a,b\mid [a,[a,b]]=[b,[a,b]]=1\rangle.$$

How to find such a copy of $H$ in $G$ with finite quotient? Can this be done by hand or are the  computer-base algorithms that find such copies? I am not an expert in group theory, so maybe this is obvious?

Comment: The group that you have defined is not torsion-free. I expect you have made a mistake copying the presentation

Comment: @DerekHolt Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the slides you link, it is mentioned this example comes from [Lindsay Jennae Soelberg's Master's thesis](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/etd/6932/). She mentions "[using] Magma as a tool to show that $G_Z$ is torsion-free [following] an idea of Derek Holt, given in response to a question at MathOverflow", which I suspect may refer to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/271348).

To quote the thesis (p24):

> Using Magma we search for a subgroup of $G_Z$ of small index and with an especially easy
> rewrite system. It yielded the following subgroup which met the qualifications we required.
> Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by the three elements $h_1 := yxy^{−1}x^{−1}$, $h_2 := y^2$, and
> $h_3 := x^4$. The group $H$ has index $8$ in $G_Z$, it is a normal subgroup, and it is given by the
> finite presentation
> $$H = \langle h_1, h_2, h_3 : h_2 \textrm{ is central, and } h_3h_1 = h_1h_3h_2^8\rangle.$$

From this presentation, it becomes clear that $K := \langle h_1,h_3\rangle$ is isomorphic to the Heisenberg group, has index $8$ in $H$ and index $64$ in $G_Z$. Do note, however, that while $K$ is normal in $H$, it is not normal in $G$.

Comment: I rechecked the calculation using Magma again, and it is correct.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I had a quick look at the thesis, but the Heisenberg group wasn't mentioned...should have had a longer look. But it seems to find H one really has to use a computer. Interesting!